# Using SWIG to interface large C-project with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot, swig

I want to access some functions from a large C-project from Python. It seems to me that SWIG is the way to go. I'm not very used to programming i C and my experience with "make" is mostly from downloading source tars. The functions I want to access resides in a large C-project (Gnuplot) and I have no idea who to use SWIG on such a large number of source files. The functions I want to access are all in a single c-file but there are many recursive includes. I would like some suggestions on how to get started.

What I want to access: term/emf.trm

Reason: Missing support for symbols an LaTex in the EMF-backend to matplotlib (this backend has even been removed from matplotlib). I'm stuck with an old version of Word at work and there is no way to get plots in this program that are suitable for my purpose without EMF. I could use Gnuplot instead of matplotlib but many of the plots are specialized for a certain purpose and matplotlib is much easier to use than Gnuplot.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You could just try using [Gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net)

Also:

A while back I wrapped Wild Magic C++ libraries (100K+ lines of code) into a Python module using SWIG (take a look at [Python Wild Magic](http://vmlaker.github.io/pythonwildmagic/swig_interface.html).)

Since the codebase contained more than 1000 C++ classes, I used [GCC-XML](http://gccxml.github.io/) to help me produce 99% of the SWIG interface file. Basically it went down like this:

1. Run gcc-xml on all header files, producing XML output
2. Obtain a listing of all names (funcs and classes) by parsing the XML
3. Run make in dry run mode, i.e. `make -n` and capture the output.
4. Parse the output to obtain a listing of all definition files (`.c` or `.cpp` or what have you) *in order of compilation*. The order is important because SWIG expects interface declarations in dependency order.
5. Parse the ordered definition files from previous step and grep all `#include` statements. Barring duplicates, these ordered #includes can be added to your SWIG interface file.

It sounds like you're only interested in a few functons instead of wrapping the whole library, so this may be an overkill. And you're working with C and Fortran, so it's a little bit different. But maybe you find the approach useful.

And this was easy to do for Wild Magic because the directory structure was pretty much flat. Gnuplot looks a little bit more modularized.

Comment: I don't want to switch to Gnuplot.py because I've invested in a lot of time making customized plots (not just curves). This would be my last resort. Matplotlib is much better in my opinion and it would be better to add EMF-supprt to Matplotlib than to redo all the code.

Comment: I see. I added an example SWIG project to the answer--you might find it useful.

Comment: +1 for suggesting SWIG and gcc-xml. Wondering if you could expand on how you used gcc-xml output.

Comment: Sure thing, I added a high level description of my approach with gcc-xml.

Comment: I'm not sure it's overkill. I'm currently thinking about using Gnuplot's terminal to Matplotlib and then it would be neat to be able to use either Gnuplot, Matplotlib or both (in the same plot function) and output it all on some of Gnuplot's terminals. Way over my horizon at the moment but I'll try to do it as general as possible. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the first few chapters of swig manual, and making some of its example projects for python, the distrib has many that illustrate many different capabilities of swig and the make files are already built so one less thing to learn.